# Alterar endpoint de healthcheck do Actuator em Spring Boot 1.5

Tags: java, spring-boot

preciso alterar o endpoint de healthcheck da minha aplicação com actuator.

Já tentei

management.endpoints.web.base-path=/teste
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=healthcheck

mas parece que isso pra Spring Boot 1.5 não funciona.

Como seria a configuração para Spring Boot 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro olhar a documentação de acordo com a versão que você está utilizando.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

Provavelmente adicionando a seguinte propriedade deve resolver seu problema:

```
endpoints.actuator.path
```